# Importance of "@" sign in MATCH function Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

What is the difference between **=MATCH(@B27:B42;I27:I42;0)** and **=MATCH(B27;I27:I42;0)** ?

Answer (score 0):

the @ sign is new excel functionality that will return only the first value of an array result. Without the @ sign the formula would create a "spilled" array of all values in your formula.

so your first formula would just return the first value from your `@B27:B42` (i.e., the match from B27).

your second formula would return one match since it is only `B27`

If your second formula was changed to `B27:B42` then the spill feature would try to work.

Comment: Based on my testing, for `=MATCH()`, `@` only works as part of a table. In this case the table would look for the second item (B28) in the next row, and so on down the table.